# Why I am getting a <class 'KeyError'> for the word location when running a location program for raspberry pi?

Tags: python, gps, location

I have this problem where when ever I run this piece of python code:

```
    import sys
    import time

    import geolocation
    import publisher

    SleepTime = 10  # seconds
    _lat = 0.00
    _lon = 0.00


     def maintain():
         global _lat
         global _lon
         (lat, lon, accuracy) = geolocation.getLocation()
         if lat != _lat or lon != _lon:
            data = str(lat) + "," + str(lon) + "," + str(accuracy)
            print("publishing ", data)
            publisher.publishtoInternet(data)
            _lat = lat
            _lon = lon
        else:
            print("no change in coordinates")


    print("program begins")
    while True:
          try:
              maintain()
    except Exception as inst:
         print(type(inst), ' exception captured')
         print(inst)
         sys.stdout.flush()
         # file = open('/tmp/locktracker.error.log','a')
         # file.write('exception occurred, trying to reboot')
         # file.close()
         # call(["sudo","reboot"])
   # break
  for i in range(0, SleepTime):
      sys.stdout.write("\restarting in %d seconds " % (SleepTime - i))
      sys.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(1)
```

using these other python scripts which are called geolocation and publisher:
geolocation:

```
     import json
     import requests


    def getLocation():
        # print lac, cellTower, operator
        payload = {'considerIp': 'true'}
        jsonPayload = json.dumps(payload)
        # print jsonPayload
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        privateKey = "<>"
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=' + 
        privateKey
        r = requests.post(url, data=jsonPayload, headers=headers)
        response = json.loads(r.text)
        # print response
       return response["location"]["lat"], response["location"]["lng"], 
       response["accuracy"]
```

publisher:

```
    import time
    import urllib


    def publishtoInternet(temp):
        url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=" + temp
        try:
            print(url)
            result = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
            print(result + str(temp))
    except:
           print('exception uploading, logging to file')
           log(temp)


def log(temp):
    f = open('log', 'a')
    t = time.localtime(time.time())
    msg = str(t.tm_hour) + ' ' + str(t.tm_min)
    f.write(msg)
    f.write('temp: ')
    f.write(temp)

    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
```

I get this error which is that for the location word, I get  and then the code restarts. This really bugs me as this is a project for my school which I have to complete. Also it seem that if i delete the location word and just keep latitude and longitude as lat and long, it come back with the same error.

Comment: I’m a beginner in python and this code is from a lot of different sources and I don’t know indentation that well. Please just try to understand and help.

Comment: The indentation is still flakey. As I said above, we can't tell what your code actually does if we have to guess at the correct indentation.

Comment: I don’t know how to fix It any more than I already have.

Comment: Also, what does "I get this error which is that for the location word, I get and then the code restarts" mean? If you're getting an error message, please paste the full Traceback into your question, in a code block to preserve the formatting.

Comment: That code won't run due to the indentation errors. So I assume that the code on your machine is better indented than that, otherwise you wouldn't get that `KeyError` message.

Comment: What does KeyError mean?

Comment: The usual way to get a `KeyError` is attempting to access an item in a dictionary with a key that's not in that dictionary. You can also get `KeyError` by attempting to remove a non-existent item from a set.

Comment: How do you get rid of one?

Comment: By not attempting to access an item in a dictionary with a key that's not in that dictionary. Either fix your logic so that can't happen, or test keys with the `in` operator before using them to index into the dictionary. Or use the `dict.get` method to supply a default value for missing keys.

Comment: I suggest that you start a new script and add just enough code to recreate the exact same error you are getting. Alternatively, use a debugger or print() statements to view the values of variables in your code so that you can figure out what it is doing.